# How to properly catch and filter all keyboard events in a QTableWidget?

Tags: qt, pyside, keyevent

I'd like to filter the characters entered in the cells of a QWidgetTable to only accept hexadecimal characters (ie filter ascii character that doesn't represent an hex value).

I tried different options and still doesn't manage to do that.

One of the option is to implement my own widget superclassing the QWidgetTable with my own keyPressEvent like this:

```
class MyQTableWidget(QTableWidget):

    def keyPressEvent(self, event):
        print("Item - Key pressed", event.key())
        super().keyPressEvent(event)
        #event.accept()
```

In this case, only the first character typed and the final "enter" key is captured by the event handler ... How to capture all characters I enter in the cell ?

I understand that the editor associated with the widget may be the one that catch all intermediate  key events, so I tried to use an QItemDelegate with an eventFilfer().
In this case, I'm able to capture all key events, however this breaks the default behavior of the widget ...

So how to proceed ?

Thanks

Comment: Filtering key-press events seems the wrong approach. Use an item-delegate with a [validator](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qvalidator.html).

Comment: I see. I'm not sure about using validator with ItemDelegate but I could use QLineEdit widgets in the cell with a validator there I guess....

Comment: No, reimplement [QItemDelegate.createEditor](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qitemdelegate.html#createEditor) and set a validator on the editor-widget. See also: [Delegate Classes](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/model-view-programming.html#delegate-classes).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot do this by handling key events on the view. The reason for which you're only getting the first key is that the view decides what to do depending on the pressed key: for instance, if you're pressing a *navigation* key (arrows, tab, page, etc), then it will change the current item.

If the [`editTriggers()`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qabstractitemview.html#editTriggers-prop) includes `AnyKeyPressed` (and the current item is editable), then it enters in edit mode, creates an editor for that index, and sends that key event to the editor.

Handling events in the delegate event filter is also discouraged, as you might filter out events that shouldn't be filtered, or you might accept invalid input when using the clipboard. In your case, <kbd>Ctrl+V</kbd> wouldn't be accessible if you're not careful, but if it would you may paste content that doesn't match the hex syntax.

The proper solution is to install a QValidator on the editor, and in this case you can use a simple [QRegExpValidator](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qregexpvalidator.html).

```
class HexDelegate(QtWidgets.QStyledItemDelegate):
    def createEditor(self, parent, opt, index):
        editor = super().createEditor(parent, opt, index)
        if isinstance(editor, QtWidgets.QLineEdit):
            regexp = QtCore.QRegExp('[A-Fa-f0-9]+')
            validator = QtGui.QRegExpValidator(regexp)
            editor.setValidator(validator)
        return editor

app = QtWidgets.QApplication([])
table = QtWidgets.QTableWidget(10, 10)
table.setItemDelegate(HexDelegate(table))
table.show()
app.exec()
```

Note that with the regexp above, the `+` means that *at least* one character must be entered in order to *accept* the input: if the field is empty and you press enter, the editor will not submit the value. If you want to accept empty values, use `[A-Fa-f0-9]*`.

If you need a specific amount of characters, use the `{}` syntax:

- to accept exactly 2 characters: `[A-Fa-f0-9]{2}`;
- to accept *at least* 2 characters: `[A-Fa-f0-9]{2,}`;
- to accept at least 2 characters, but not more than 5: `[A-Fa-f0-9]{2,5}`;

Alternatively, when the input has a defined maximum length, you can use the line edit [`inputMask`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qlineedit.html#inputMask-prop):

```
class HexDelegate(QtWidgets.QStyledItemDelegate):
    def createEditor(self, parent, opt, index):
        editor = super().createEditor(parent, opt, index)
        if isinstance(editor, QtWidgets.QLineEdit):
            editor.setInputMask('HHHHH;_')
        return editor
```

The above will require exactly 5 hexadecimal characters, but you can also *require* at least 2 characters (but no more than 5), using `HHhhh;_`. Note that the input mask cannot accept undefined number of characters, so in that case you should choose the validator solution above.

Comment: Great, thanks for the detailed and helpful explanations (it matches what I observed and I understood, and the solution is what I attempted to do yesterday ... without success so far).
Also, just a very minor / cosmetic changes: I use this one-line validator creation
`editor.setValidator(QRegularExpressionValidator("[0-fA-F]+"))`